# How do you integrate the indicator function?

Tags: integration

This is a specific example.

Let g(x) = $\int$$\vert$$f(u)$$\vert$$du$

where $f(u)$ = $1_{[0, 1/2]}$($u$)

What does g(x) look like, is the indicator function treated as constant when integrating?

and what does it compute if, let's say, the limits of g(x) are o to 1?
If limits are 0 and 1 and indicator treated as constant, i get g(x) = 0, but I've seen somewhere it is equal to 1/2 with no workings?

Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: the definition of $g$ has no sense. Maybe you mean $g(x)=\int_{-\infty }^x f(u)\,\mathrm d u$ ?

Comment: yes i meant that, exept the lower limit (-inf) would be 0 i think

Comment: The absolute value is an unnecessary complication: the image of $f$ is a subset of $\{0,1\}$, therefore $\lvert f\rvert=f$. As for the rest, Surb's comment is quite relevant.

Comment: So if the limits are 0 to 1 does it equal 0 ?